# Access to function variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and I am a beginner. I have this structure:

```
function a(){
   function b(){
     return x;
   }
}
```

I want to return `x` from primary function that is `a()`. How can I do this?

Comment: Just  return function's b value

Comment: You just call `b()` in `a`'s body.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: @A.Wolff: that's right

Comment: @A.Wolff http://i.stack.imgur.com/rGtMH.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

Assuming:

```
var x = 1;
```

You could do this:

```
// Return a function when calling `a()`, which can be called --> `a()()`;
function a() {
    return function b (){
        return x;
    }
}

a()(); // 1;
```

```
// Return the result of `b()` when calling `a()`;
function a(){
    function b(){
        return x;
    }
    return b();
}

a(); // 1;
```

```
// Return a object containing a function named `b`.
function a(){
    return {
        b: function(){
            return x;
        }
    };
}

a().b(); // 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function a() {
    return b();
   function b (){

     return x;
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess somebody downvoting everybody's answer here @A.Wolff

Comment: @Neel: Looks like it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this?

```
function a() {
    function b (){
        return x;
    }
    return b();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner version of answer :

```
function a(){
    function b(){
        return x;
    }
    return b();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
function a(){
    return b();
}

function b(){
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amHZ2/):

```
function a() {
    var x = 34;
    return function b (){
        return x;
    }
}

var f1 = a();
var f2 = f1();
alert(f2); //34
```